# How to handle multiple elements in SVG with D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have multiple elements in SVG .

```
<svg width=200 height=200>
<g id='a'>
  <circle cx=40 cy=30 r=15></circle>
  <rect x=60 y=20 width=40 height=20></rect>
</g>
<g id='b'>
  <circle cx=40 cy=90 r=15></circle>
</g>
</svg>
```

My goal is to select the elements in D3 and change the color. like from a circle as gold and circle from b as green and rectangle from b as blue.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this dynamically -- rather than just setting the `fill` attribute of each element directly -- then you can use [`d3.select`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#select) to select the elements and then [`selection.attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) to modify their `fill`.

Here's a working example:

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.select('g#a circle').attr('fill', 'gold');
svg.select('g#a rect').attr('fill', 'blue');
svg.select('g#b circle').attr('fill', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=200 height=200>
<g id='a'>
  <circle cx=40 cy=30 r=15></circle>
  <rect x=60 y=20 width=40 height=20></rect>
</g>
<g id='b'>
  <circle cx=40 cy=90 r=15></circle>
</g>
</svg>
```

Note that there is no `<rect>` in `<g id='b'>` in your original example, so this example just changes the `<rect>` in `<g id='a'>`.